# nodejs- not able to save data returned by an asynchronous function

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I'm getting undefined when I trying to print a value to console which is returned by an asynchronous function.

This is happening in my controller function (`dumyController.js`) which calls a function written in helper (`DBHelper.js`), for DRY approach, which 
asynchronously fetches data from a model function in `DBHelperModel.js`

**dumyController.js**

```
var dbHelpers = require('../helpers/helpers');
exports.dumyControllerFunc = function (req, res) {
  var result= dbHelpers.dumyHelperFunc(165);
  console.log(result);
};
```

**DBHelper.js**

```
var dbHelp = require('../models/DBHelperModel');
module.exports = {
  dumyHelperFunc: function (userId) {
    dbHelp.fetchDataFromDB(userId, function (err, rows) {
        var res;
        if (err) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            res.send(rows.member_code);
        }
    });
  }
};
```

**DBHelperModel.js**

```
var db = require('../db');
var DBHelpers = {
  fetchDataFromDB: function (userId, callback) {
    var query = `SELECT member_code FROM members where id=?`;
    db.query(query, userId, callback);
  },
};
module.exports = DBHelpers;
```

**db.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createPool({
    host: '127.0.01',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'dumyDB'
});
module.exports = connection;
```

I know I'm not getting value because of the asynchronous nature of the function but can anyone tell me how to fetch the value with an architecture like given above. I'm new to nodeJS. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a solution about the asynchronous in nodejs.

- The [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise),that is a universal and popular solution
- Use a `callback`,That is a approach in nodejs's way,anyway,that is native nodejs's asynchronous solution .
- Other asysn: [Generate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) and [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), that's es6 feature,and the latter is support by nodejs7+

The `promise` is most recommend,it has a good looks structure if has a asycn chain, The `callback` looks bad on that.

Comment: Can you share a sample? The link you provided for promise is of Chinese font I guess. Even after translating the page, half of the content is still in the Chinese language. @sinbar

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you trying to achieve:
https://repl.it/MA0Z/0

```
var DBHelpers = {
    fetchDataFromDB: function (userId, callback) {
      callback(null, 'hello fetchDataFromDB');
   },
};

 var dbhelp = {
    dumyHelperFunc: function (userId, callback) {
      DBHelpers.fetchDataFromDB(userId, function (err, rows) {
         if (err) {
            callback('error bro');
         } else {
            callback(null, rows);
         }
    });
  }
}

dbhelp.dumyHelperFunc(165, function (error, result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: This didn't work. I'm getting undefined in console after changing the code like you mentioned. @Levarne Sobotker

Comment: It's not working. I ran the fiddle you provided. I'm getting undefined in that as well. I don't think this will yield results.